# PDF Javascript counter

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to give a text field a value that is equal to the amount of text fields filled out using a counter. So if for example 3 out of the 10 fields are greater than 0, I want the event value to be 3. When I apply the code it does do anything. Any suggestions.

```
var cnt = 0;
var v1 = getField("A").value!="" ? getField("A").value : 0;
var v2 = getField("B").value!="" ? getField("B").value : 0;
var v3 = getField("C").value!="" ? getField("C").value : 0;
var v4 = getField("D").value!="" ? getField("D").value : 0;
var v5 = getField("E").value!="" ? getField("E").value : 0;
var v6 = getField("F").value!="" ? getField("F").value : 0;
var v7 = getField("G").value!="" ? getField("G").value : 0;
var v8 = getField("H").value!="" ? getField("H").value : 0;
var v9 = getField("I").value!="" ? getField("I").value : 0;
var v10 = getField("J").value!="" ? getField("J").value : 0;


if (this.getField("v1").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v2").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v3").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v4").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v5").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v7").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v8").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v9").value > 0){
cnt++;
}
if (this.getField("v10").value > 0){
cnt++;
}


event.value = cnt;
```

Comment: and what is `event.value` at the end?

Comment: even value is the amount for "cnt"

Answer (score 0):

Yikes… (sorry 'bout that), but the whole thing could be simplified a lot. Try something in this line (and add this script to the Calculate event of the field showing the number of filled fields):

```
var cntr = 0 ;
var myFields = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
for (var i = 0 ; i < myFields.length ; i++) {
if (this.getField(myFields[i]).value != this.getField(myFields[i]).defaultValue) {
cntr++ ;
}
event.value = cntr ;
```

And that should do it; you may have to adjust the `myFields` array according to your field names.

The original code won't work, because in the first block, you define a variable v1 (for example), which will then be assigned a field value or 0. In the second block, you look at a field named "v1" and evaluate whether it is greater than 0.

There is no connection between the first and the second block.